# How to generate a position independent executable with nasm and ld?

Tags: gcc, nasm, ld, position-independent-code

I have a simple nasm code:

**test.nasm**

```
section .text

global _start

_start:
    jmp _start
    ret
```

I build it as below:

```
nasm -f elf64 test.nasm -o test.o
ld test.o -o test -pie
```

Then I tried to run it:

```
./test
```

It gives me this:

```
bash: ./test: No such file or directory
```

So I checked the file header:

```
readelf -h test
```

It shows this:

```
ELF Header:
  Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 02 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
  Class:                             ELF64
  Data:                              2's complement, little endian
  Version:                           1 (current)
  OS/ABI:                            UNIX - System V
  ABI Version:                       0
  Type:                              DYN (Shared object file) <====== NOT an executable
  Machine:                           Advanced Micro Devices X86-64
  Version:                           0x1
  Entry point address:               0x1f0
  Start of program headers:          64 (bytes into file)
  Start of section headers:          4616 (bytes into file)
  Flags:                             0x0
  Size of this header:               64 (bytes)
  Size of program headers:           56 (bytes)
  Number of program headers:         6
  Size of section headers:           64 (bytes)
  Number of section headers:         12
  Section header string table index: 11
```

But I can easily create a **position independent executable** with GCC for below program:

**test2.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main(void)
{
    printf("hello, pie!\n");
}
```

I build it with:

```
gcc test2.c -o test2 -pie
```

It runs like this:

```
hello, pie!
```

So how can I create a position independent **executable** with `nasm` and `ld` rather than a shared object?

### ADD 1

I checked the `test2` ELF header. It is also a shared object. So it may not be the problem. (Thanks to @Nate Eldredge)

```
ELF Header:
  Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 02 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
  Class:                             ELF64
  Data:                              2's complement, little endian
  Version:                           1 (current)
  OS/ABI:                            UNIX - System V
  ABI Version:                       0
  Type:                              DYN (Shared object file) <===== ALSO a shared object
  Machine:                           Advanced Micro Devices X86-64
  Version:                           0x1
  Entry point address:               0x530
  Start of program headers:          64 (bytes into file)
  Start of section headers:          6440 (bytes into file)
  Flags:                             0x0
  Size of this header:               64 (bytes)
  Size of program headers:           56 (bytes)
  Number of program headers:         9
  Size of section headers:           64 (bytes)
  Number of section headers:         29
  Section header string table index: 28
```

So how can I use `ld` to get a position-independent executable from the object file generated with `nasm`?

Comment: Executables are still of type DYN (check some others), so that's not your problem.

Comment: Simply doing `gcc -nostdlib -o test test.o` works for me.

Comment: Thanks but I want to use `ld` rather than `gcc`.

Comment: Add `-v` to the gcc call, then you'll see how `ld` is called by gcc.